# stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload" - Python FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, fastapi

I am integrating Stripe API with Firebase using Fastapi and I am facing the issue - "stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload"

The code is working in local testing with Stripe CLI but doesn't work in deployment. The error is on the last line.

```
async def feathers_buy_update(request: Request):
    """Endpoint to handle the Stripe session status updates like checkout completed or checkout expired

    Args:

    """
    event = None
    payload = await request.body()
    sig_header = request.headers.get("stripe-signature")
    endpoint_secret = "<endpoint_secret>"

    event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret)
```

I printed the type of all three inputs. Payload - bytes, sig_header - string, endpoint_secret - string.

Comment: If you have already checked you're using the right secret, I would double check the payload is exactly the same you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different reasons you could be hitting verification issues, but usually when you hit these issues after already confirming things work locally during testing it's one of the following:

- You're using the wrong webhook endpoint secret. When testing with the Stripe CLI you get back a webhook secret (`whsec_123`) from the `stripe listen` command, but a lot of people forget to replace it once they deploy their real webhook endpoint. Make sure the webhook secret you have in your code matches what is displayed in the dashboard (when you open the webhook endpoint in the Stripe dashboard you'll see a section where you can "Reveal" the Signing Secret).
- Your production server has some kind of configuration or setting in place that's manipulating the raw body/payload which wasn't set while testing locally. This will really depend on your framework - you'll probably want to log the `payload` as a string to confirm whether it looks correct first.

Comment: I checked the first point and I have passed the correct secret. For the second issue, I am not even sure what to look for in the payload. The payload seems to printing as bytes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. As most of the documentation and examples from Stripe uses either Flask or Django, it is not clear how you should get the headers from the request with FastAPI.

I took the same aproach as you using the `request.headers.get("stripe-signature")` method, the one that you would normally try when using FastAPI, but it gave the same error you get.

After searching in the [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) (the library which FastAPI is build upon) i found that you can access to the headers as a list with `request.headers['stripe-signature']` and this way it will work. I am not really sure why, but i hope this solution works for you too.